# Jquery .change function firing multple times with checkboxes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, linux, syntax

Basically i have a group of checkboxes with the name `moneylineaway` and im trying to detect when one is checked or unchecked and get the id for that checkbox for later use, and it is firing unlimited times when i check one.

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      $("input[name='moneylineaway']").change(function() {
         if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
         }
         else {
            //do nothing yet
         }
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: would you not get an alert for every moneylineaway element that was checked? not just the one that was selected?

Comment: none are checked by default, when i load this up and check one it keeps firing.

Comment: i even tried `$("input[name='moneylineaway']").click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("input[name='moneylineaway']").change(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
        }
        else{
            //do nothing yet
        }
        });

    });
```

You can see the working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/FKWSp/

Comment: im getting the following

[01:43:02.189] TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null @ http://www.yourisk.com/?content=odds2&id=mlb:134
[01:43:02.195] Empty string passed to getElementById(). @ http://www.yourisk.com/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3

Comment: The fiddle works. I don't see any matching checkboxes on the url you provided.

Comment: also where's that `document.getElementById()` ? code is too simple, does not have a problem..

Comment: I guess maybe i just suck at copy & paste. It's working thank you.